# Wordpress add_filter for custom content

Tags: wordpress, add-filter

Can anyone tell me how I can use the add_filter function to chance the plugin_dir_path of a page?

When I use get_post_type() to set a temple for my movie_reviews there is no problem 
But I dont know how to use the function on a none register_post_type.

I like to use a custom page on the url www.domain.com/user_profile 
and in a form action action="search_result" 
But I don't know how this works on a none register_post_type

```
add_filter( 'template_include','include_template_function', 1 );

function include_template_function( $template_path ) {

    if ( get_post_type() == 'movie_reviews' ) {
        $template_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) .'/single-movie_reviews.php';
    }
    if ( ....... == 'search_sesult' ) {
        $template_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) .'/movie-searchresult_reviews.php';
    }
    if ( ....... == 'user_profile' ) {
        $template_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) .'/user_profile.php';
    }   


    return $template_path;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**Conditional Tags**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) for this.

For example:

```
add_filter( 'template_include','include_template_function', 1 );

function include_template_function( $template_path ) {

    if( is_search() ) 
        $template_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) .'/movie-searchresult_reviews.php';

    if( is_author() ) 
        $template_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) .'/user_profile.php';


    return $template_path;
}
```